# android enter key event not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

jquery:

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#search').blur();
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <input id="search" type="text">
 </div>
```

I want to `detect` the `enter` (or go) `key event` in `jquery` when the key is pressed on `mobile devices` like `android`, once the key is pressed, i need to `blur` the input box field.

but my above of jquery code is `not working`. please help me.

Comment: Should use [`e.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) in jQuery.

Comment: Use keyup/keydown event instead of keypress.

Comment: @e.which is not worked for me, then only I tried with e.keycode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reedit:

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(e) { 
if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
$('#search').blur(); 
} 
});
```

Comment: `e.keyCode == 66` also not works

Comment: Cound you log your key code before if block?Check whether keypress was invoked?

Comment: i was trying from mobile, then how can i log the event?

Comment: Add a label in your html and setting keycode as label's value after key press,is it can be done?

Comment: thanks for the help, and i got the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182838/discussion-between-logakrishnan-and-aolphn).